# Querying Google Maps Using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to pass the Latitude and Longitude as a variable in PHP to fetch static Google Maps , But this just picks up one Image despite of changing the co ordinates .Please help

*

```
<?php 
session_start();
$latitude=doubleval($_POST['latitude']);
$longitude=doubleval($_POST['longitude']);
$cordinate=$latitude.",".$longitude;
$cordinate1=doubleval($cordinate);
echo $latitude;
echo $longitude;
$src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=($latitude,$longitude)&zoom=20&size=640x640&maptype=satellite&key=MyKey';
$time=strval(mktime());
$destfolder='images/';
$mapImgName=$time."google-map.PNG";
$imagePath=$destfolder.$mapImgName
file_put_contents($imagePath,file_get_contents($src));
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imagePath; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it double quotes so that the $latitude and $longitude variables are read

with single quotes your string is reading as

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=($latitude,$longitude)&zoom=20&size=640x640&maptype=satellite&key=MyKey

where as you want it to read as

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=(5,10)&zoom=20&size=640x640&maptype=satellite&key=MyKey

so change your string to

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=($latitude,$longitude)&zoom=20&size=640x640&maptype=satellite&key=MyKey";
```

source [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: The variables however are not taking float values due to some reason can you please cite what the possible cause could be

Comment: I tried moving the images returned from Google Map and save it to mongo DB but the image won't return again
$mapImgName=$time."google-map.PNG";
$imagePath=$destfolder.$mapImgName;
file_put_contents($imagePath,file_get_contents($src));
MongoCursor::$timeout = -1;
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->mydb;
$grid = $db->getGridFS();
$path = "$destfolder";
$filename=$mapImgName;
$storedfile = $grid->storeFile("$imagePath", array("metadata" => array("filename" => $filename,"date"=>new MongoDate()))); 
echo gettype($imagePath);
?>
<img src="<?php echo "$imagePath"; ?>">